# The difference between '=' and '==' in logical indices

Tags: r

```
x <- -3:3
x[x=2]/x[x==2] = -1
```

Why the numerator `x[x=2]` equals `-2`?

Can anybody explain the difference between `=` and `==` in logical indices?

Comment: If you see this in your code base there is a >99% chance it's a typo and therefore a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is doing assignment here, not comparison. When you do assignment, by default the right hand side value is returned. Observe

```
print(x=2)
# [1] 2
print(x=100)
# [1] 100
print(x<-2)
# [1] 2
```

so it's the same as

```
x[2]/x[x==2]
```

and

```
x[2]
# [1] -2
```

so -2/2 is -1.

You should generally avoid `=` except for naming parameters passed to functions. Use `<-` for assignment, and `==` for comparison. That way when you see a `=` in `[]` it jumps out as being "wrong"